# Web application with Flask through a Colab notebook

Tags: python, html, flask, web, google-colaboratory

I have a Python code in the format of a Colab notebook, and I would like to share the results of this code on a web page. Additionally, I want to have a field where users can input values to execute the code.

The objective of my code is to predict stock market actions using a recurrent neural network with a genetic algorithm. The data is extracted from Yahoo Finance. To present the results on a web page, I am using the Flask framework.

My project is organized as follows: I have a folder that contains the Python code in the format of a Colab notebook. Inside this folder, there is a subfolder called "template" which contains two files: "index.html" and "result.html".

When executing the code, I am encountering a problem. It enters an infinite loop and does not finish the execution or display an error message. The only output I get is the following:

```
* Serving Flask app '__main__'
 * Debug mode: on
INFO:werkzeug:WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
INFO:werkzeug:Press CTRL+C to quit
INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat
```

When I try to access the link http://127.0.0.1:5000, I receive the error message: "The connection to 127.0.0.1 was refused".

The file "index.html" contains the structure for input data insertion, while the file "result.html" displays the charts and financial stock values.

File "index.html":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Neural Finance Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Neural Finance Project</h1>
    <form action="/result" method="post">
        <label for="ticker">Ticker:</label>
        <input type="text" name="ticker" id="ticker"><br><br>
        <label for="start_date">Start Date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date"><br><br>
        <label for="end_date">End Date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Run Project">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

File "result.html":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Neural Finance Project - Result</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Neural Finance Project - Result</h1>
    <h2>Ticker: {{ ticker }}</h2>
    <h2>Start Date: {{ start_date }}</h2>
    <h2>End Date: {{ end_date }}</h2>

    <div class="quadro">
      <div class="item">
        <span class="titulo">Ticket: </span>
        <span class="valor">{{ ticker }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <span class="titulo">Período: </span>
        <span class="valor">{{ start_date }} a {{ end_date }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />

    <h2 class="grafico-title">Gráfico Valor de Fechamento</h2>
    <div>
      <img
        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='chart01.png') }}"
        alt="Chart 01"
      />
    </div>
    <h2 class="grafico-title">Gráfico Candlestick</h2>
    <div>
      <img
        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='chart02.png') }}"
        alt="Chart 02"
      />
    </div>
    <h2 class="grafico-title">Gráfico MACD</h2>
    <div>
      <img
        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='chart03.png') }}"
        alt="Chart 03"
      />
    </div>
    <h2 class="grafico-title">Gráfico RSI</h2>
    <div>
      <img
        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='chart04.png') }}"
        alt="Chart 04"
      />
    </div>
    <h2 class="grafico-title">Gráfico Recurrent Neural Network (RNN)</h2>
    <div>
      <img
        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='chart05.png') }}"
        alt="Chart 05"
      />
    </div>
    <h2 class="grafico-title">Gráfico Genetic Algorithm (GA)</h2>
    <div>
      <img
        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='chart06.png') }}"
        alt="Chart 06"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="quadro">
      <div class="item">
        <span class="titulo">Recomendação: </span>
        <span class="valor">{{ recommendation }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <span class="titulo">Preço previsto $: </span>
        <span class="valor">{{ predicted_value }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the script I am using:

```
# Libraries update
!pip install --upgrade pandas
!pip install yfinance
!pip install ta==0.10.2
!pip install scikit-learn
!pip install tensorflow
!pip install flask
```

```
# Importing libraries

import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ta
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from enum import Enum
from ta.utils import dropna
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
yf.pdr_override()
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/result', methods=['POST'])
def result():
    # Input data
    # Download actual stock prices from Yahoo Finance
    ticker = request.form['ticker']
    start_date = request.form['start_date']
    end_date = request.form['end_date']

    # Recurrent Neural Network (RNN)

    # Values for the Recurrent Neural Network (RNN)
    stock_dataRNN = yf.download(ticker, start=start_date, end=end_date)

    # Obtain the MACD technical indicator via the Technical Analysis Library.
    macd = ta.trend.MACD(close=stock_dataRNN['Close'])
    stock_dataRNN['MACD'] = macd.macd_diff()

    # Obtain the RSI technical indicator via the Technical Analysis Library.
    stock_dataRNN['RSI'] = ta.momentum.RSIIndicator(stock_dataRNN['Close']).rsi()

    # Create a new dataframe with only the 'Close' column data of the stock_dataRNN
    data = stock_dataRNN.filter(['Close'])

    # Convert the dataframe to a numpy array
    dataset = data.values

    # Get the number of rows to train the model and determined that the training data set contains about 80% of the data.
    training_data_len = math.ceil(len(dataset)*.8)
    training_data_len

    # Scale all data to values between 0 and 1
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

    # Create scaled training dataset
    train_data = scaled_data[0:training_data_len, :]

    # Split the data into x_train and y_train datasets
    x_train = []
    y_train = []
    for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
        x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0])
        y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])

    # Convert x_train and y_train into numpy arrays
    x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

    # Reshape the data into the format accepted by LSTM
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))

    # Build the LSTM network model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
    model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(units=25))
    model.add(Dense(units=1))

    # Compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

    # Train the model
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

    # Test data set
    test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len - 60: , : ]

    #Create the x_test and y_test data sets
    x_test = []
    y_test =  dataset[training_data_len : , : ] 
    for i in range(60,len(test_data)):
        x_test.append(test_data[i-60:i,0])

    # Convert x_test to a numpy arrays 
    x_test = np.array(x_test)

    # Reshape the data into the shape accepted by the LSTM
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1],1))

    # Getting the models predicted price values
    predictions = model.predict(x_test, verbose=0)
    predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)

    # Calculate/Get the value of RMSE
    rmse=np.sqrt(np.mean(((predictions- y_test)**2)))

    # Predict actual price of the next day:
    next_day = data.tail(60).values
    next_day_scaled = scaler.transform(next_day)
    next_day_reshaped = np.reshape(next_day_scaled, (1, next_day.shape[0], 1))
    next_day_prediction = model.predict(next_day_reshaped, verbose=0)
    next_day_prediction = scaler.inverse_transform(next_day_prediction)
    #print("Next day prediction:", next_day_prediction[0][0])

    # Genetic Algorithm (GA)

    # Values for the Genetic Algorithm (GA)
    stock_dataGA = yf.download(ticker, start=start_date, end=end_date)["Adj Close"].values

    # Define the chromosome
    chromosome_size = 2
    min_weight = -1
    max_weight = 1
    chromosome = np.random.uniform(low=min_weight, high=max_weight, size=chromosome_size)

    # Define the fitness function
    def fitness_function(weights, stock_dataGA):
        predicted_prices = predict_prices(weights, stock_dataGA)
        mse = np.mean((predicted_prices - stock_dataGA)**2)
        return -mse  # Negative because we want to maximize fitness

    # Define the function to predict future stock prices
    def predict_prices(weights, stock_dataGA):
        # Use a simple linear model to predict future stock prices
        num_prices = len(stock_dataGA)
        future_prices = np.zeros(num_prices)
        for i in range(1, num_prices):
            future_prices[i] = stock_dataGA[i-1] * weights[0] + weights[1]
        return future_prices

    # Initialize the population
    population_size = 50
    population = [np.random.uniform(low=min_weight, high=max_weight, size=chromosome_size) for _ in range(population_size)]

    # Set termination criteria
    max_generations = 100
    target_fitness = 1000

    # Keep track of best fitness and chromosome
    best_fitness = -float('inf')
    best_chromosome = None
    fitness_history = []

    # Run genetic algorithm
    for generation in range(max_generations):
        # Evaluate the fitness
        fitness_scores = [fitness_function(chromosome, stock_dataGA) for chromosome in population]

        # Selection
        tournament_size = 5
        selected_indices = []
        for _ in range(population_size):
            tournament_indices = np.random.choice(range(population_size), size=tournament_size, replace=False)
            tournament_fitness_scores = [fitness_scores[i] for i in tournament_indices]
            winner_index = tournament_indices[np.argmax(tournament_fitness_scores)]
            selected_indices.append(winner_index)
        selected_population = [population[i] for i in selected_indices]

        # Crossover
        crossover_probability = 0.8
        offspring = []
        for i in range(0, population_size, 2):
            parent1 = selected_population[i]
            parent2 = selected_population[i+1]
            if random.random() < crossover_probability:
                crossover_point = random.randint(0, chromosome_size-1)
                child1 = np.concatenate((parent1[:crossover_point], parent2[crossover_point:]))
                child2 = np.concatenate((parent2[:crossover_point], parent1[crossover_point:]))
            else:
                child1 = parent1
                child2 = parent2
            offspring.append(child1)
            offspring.append(child2)

        # Mutation
        mutation_probability = 0.1
        for i in range(population_size):
            chromosome = offspring[i]
            for j in range(chromosome_size):
                if random.random() < mutation_probability:
                    chromosome[j] = np.random.uniform(low=min_weight, high=max_weight)
            offspring[i] = chromosome

        # Create the next generation
        population = offspring

        # Update best fitness and chromosome
        best_index = np.argmax(fitness_scores)
        if fitness_scores[best_index] > best_fitness:
          best_fitness = fitness_scores[best_index]
          best_chromosome = population[best_index]
          
        # Print progress
        #print(f"Generation: {generation+1} - Best Fitness: {-best_fitness:.2f}")

    # Predict future stock price
    future_price = predict_prices(best_chromosome, stock_dataGA)[-1]

    # Buy, Sell, or Hold recommendation
    class Recommendation(Enum):
        BUY = "Buy"
        SELL = "Sell"
        HOLD = "Hold"

    def get_recommendation(best_fitness):
        if best_fitness >= 0.5:
            return Recommendation.SELL
        elif best_fitness <= -0.5:
            return Recommendation.BUY
        else:
            return Recommendation.HOLD

    recommendation = get_recommendation(-best_fitness)
    #print("Next day prediction:", future_price)
    #print("Recommendation:", recommendation.value)

    # Free Plan Output

    # Historical Series: Closing Price

    # Plot historical closing price.
    plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))
    plt.title('Close Price History')
    plt.plot(stock_dataRNN['Close'])
    plt.xlabel('Date',fontsize=10)
    plt.ylabel('Close Price USD ($)',fontsize=18)
    plt.show()

    # Save the figure as an image
    plt.savefig('chart01.png')

    # Basic Plan Output

    # Historical Series: Candlestick Chart

    # Plot historical series via Candlestick chart.
    candlestick = go.Figure(data=go.Ohlc(
        x=stock_dataRNN.index,
        open=stock_dataRNN['Open'],
        high=stock_dataRNN['High'],
        low=stock_dataRNN['Low'],
        close=stock_dataRNN['Close']
    ))
    candlestick.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
    candlestick.update_layout(title_text='Candlestick', title_x=0.5)
    candlestick.update_layout(yaxis_title='Price')
    candlestick.update_layout(xaxis_title='Period')
    candlestick.show()

    # Save the figure as an image
    candlestick.write_image('chart02.png')

    # Historical Series: MACD Technical Indicator Chart

    # Display data via MACD technical indicator chart.
    plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))
    plt.title("MACD",fontsize=22)
    plt.xlabel('Period',fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('Variation',fontsize=18)
    plt.plot(macd.macd(), label='AMD MACD', color='blue',linewidth = 2)
    plt.plot(macd.macd_signal(), label='Signal Line', color='red', linestyle = 'dashdot', linewidth = 3)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=(20))

    # Save the figure as an image
    plt.savefig('chart03.png')

    # Historical Series: Display data via RSI technical indicator chart


    plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))
    plt.title("RSI", fontsize=22)
    stock_dataRNN['RSI'].plot(color="blue")
    plt.axhline(y=30, color='black', linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(y=70, color='black', linestyle='--')
    plt.axhspan(30, 70, color='wheat')
    plt.ylim(0, 100)
    plt.xlabel('Period',fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('Index',fontsize=18)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=(20))

    # Save the figure as an image
    plt.savefig('chart04.png')

    # Premium Plan Output

    # RNN Chart

    # Add predictions column to the data DataFrame
    data['Predictions'] = np.nan
    data.iloc[training_data_len:len(predictions)+training_data_len, -1] = predictions

    # Split the data into training and validation sets
    train = data[:training_data_len]
    valid = data[training_data_len:]

    # Visualize the data
    plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))
    plt.title('Recurrent Neural Network Stock Prices - Actual Value vs Predicted Value', fontsize=18)
    plt.xlabel('Time (Years)', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('Price (USD)', fontsize=18)
    plt.plot(train['Close'])
    plt.plot(valid[['Close', 'Predictions']])
    plt.legend(['Actual Prices', 'Actual Prices Validation', 'Predicted Prices'], loc='lower right')

    # Save the figure as an image
    plt.savefig('chart05.png')

    # GA Chart

    # Print the final chart
    best_predicted_prices = predict_prices(best_chromosome, stock_dataGA)
    plt.figure(figsize=(30,12))
    plt.plot(stock_dataGA, label="Actual Prices")
    plt.plot(best_predicted_prices, label="Predicted Prices")
    plt.title("Genetic Algorithm Stock Prices - Actual Value vs Predicted Value", fontsize=18)
    plt.xlabel("Time (Days)", fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel("Price (USD)", fontsize=18)
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    plt.show()

    # Save the figure as an image
    plt.savefig('chart06.png')

    # Recommendation value

    print("Recommendation:", recommendation.value)

    # Predicted value

    predictedValue = (future_price + next_day_prediction[0][0])/2
    print(f"Predicted value: {predictedValue}")

    return render_template('results.html', ticker=ticker, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What possible elements are missing for this application to work correctly? I look forward to your suggestions! Thank you in advance.